# Taking a list of command line parameters using Rust's CLAP Parser trait

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to have a CLI tool that redacts files according to some specified regexes.

In debugging, as an example:

```
cargo run -- folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip
```

Or in production, as an example:

```
raf folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip
```

`folder` is a subcommand, the first parameter is the path to the `folder` and the `-t` or `--types` parameter is supposed to have a list of regexes types (e.g. a regex corresponding to email, that corresponding to ip addresses and so on).

Below is a list of structs that attempted to achieve this:

```
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand, Args};

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
#[clap(author, version, about, name = "raf")]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    pub cmd: FileOrFolder,
}

#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
pub enum FileOrFolder {
    #[clap(name = "folder")]
    Folder(FolderOpts),
    #[clap(name = "file")]
    File(FileOpts),
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct FolderOpts {
    /// `path` of the directory in which all files should be redacted, e.g. ./tests/test_files
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str))]
    pub path: std::path::PathBuf,

    /// The type of redaction to be applied to the files, e.g. -t sgNRIC emails
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub types: Vec<String>,
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct FileOpts {
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str))]
    pub path: std::path::PathBuf,
    #[clap(short, long)]
    pub types: Vec<String>,
}
```

Basically, the field `types` of structs `FolderOpts` and `FileOpts` is problematic.

The runtime error is:

```
... raf> cargo run -- folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.26s
     Running `target\debug\raf.exe folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip`
error: Found argument 'ip' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    raf.exe folder [OPTIONS] <PATH>

For more information try --help
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\raf.exe folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip` (exit code: 2)
```

How do I make `-t emails, ip` to translate to `FolderOpts.types` = `vec!["emails", "ip"]`?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple arguments to the same option in `clap` 4.0 or newer you can use [`num_args`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.1.13/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.num_args):

```rust
use clap::Parser;
#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Opts {
    #[arg(short, long, num_args = 1..)]
    types: Vec<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let o = Opts::parse_from(["program_name", "-t", "first", "second"]);
    dbg!(o);
}
```

output:

```
[src/main.rs:10] o = Opts {
    types: [
        "first",
        "second",
    ],
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7a85313e8db251fbfea3e0b1d553032)

Comment: In that case you're using an old version of `clap` and should specify the exact version in your question (or just update to 4.*).

Comment: My `clap` version is `3.2.8`, upgrading to `4.x.x` gives me problem with parsing a `path` field as an `OsStr`, do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: About the `OsStr` they [work for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4ee20519f48f5f54c659b94b58b99b1) if you can't figure it out you could ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For clap:3.2.8, the following works:

```
#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct FileOpts {
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str), required=true)]
    pub path: std::path::PathBuf,
    #[clap(short, long, required=true, multiple_values=true)]
    pub types: Vec<String>,
}
```

You'll have to set `multiple_values` to be `true` in the derive macro.